# Discrepancies in PySpark DataFrame Results When Using Window Functions and Filters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

When I do certain types of transformations on a dataframe that involve window functions with filters I am getting the wrong results. Here is a minimal example of the results I get with my code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as w
from datetime import datetime, date
from chispa.dataframe_comparer import assert_df_equality

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled", True).getOrCreate()

# Base dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, date(2023, 10, 1), date(2023, 10, 2), "open"),
        (1, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 3), "close"),
        (2, date(2023, 10, 1), date(2023, 10, 2), "close"),
        (2, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 4), "close"),
        (3, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 4), "open"),
        (3, date(2023, 10, 3), date(2023, 10, 6), "open"),
    ],
    schema="id integer, date_start date, date_end date, status string"
)

# We define two partition functions
partition = w.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date_start", "date_end").rowsBetween(w.unboundedPreceding, w.unboundedFollowing)
partition2 = w.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date_start", "date_end")

# Define dataframe A
A = df.withColumn(
    "date_end_of_last_close",
    f.max(f.when(f.col("status") == "close", f.col("date_end"))).over(partition)
).withColumn(
    "rank",
    f.row_number().over(partition2)
)
display(A)

| id | date_start | date_end   | status | date_end_of_last_close | rank |
|----|------------|------------|--------|------------------------|------|
| 1  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | open   | 2023-10-03             | 1    |
| 1  | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-03 | close  | 2023-10-03             | 2    |
| 2  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | close  | 2023-10-04             | 1    |
| 2  | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-04 | close  | 2023-10-04             | 2    |
| 3  | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-04 | open   | NULL                   | 1    |
| 3  | 2023-10-03 | 2023-10-06 | open   | NULL                   | 2    |

# When filtering by rank = 1, I get this weird result
A_result = A.filter(f.col("rank") == 1).drop("rank")
display(A_result)

| id | date_start | date_end   | status | date_end_of_last_close |
|----|------------|------------|--------|------------------------|
| 1  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | open   | NULL                   |
| 2  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | close  | 2023-10-02             |
| 3  | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-04 | open   | NULL                   |
```

Obviously this result is not correct, moreover, if I create the dataframe from scratch and apply the filter I do not get the same:

```py
# Define the schema as a string
schema = "id INT, date_start DATE, date_end DATE, status STRING, date_end_of_last_close DATE, rank INT"

# Define the same data as A dataframe
data = [
    (1, date(2023, 10, 1), date(2023, 10, 2), "open", date(2023, 10, 3), 1),
    (1, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 3), "close", date(2023, 10, 3), 2),
    (2, date(2023, 10, 1), date(2023, 10, 2), "close", date(2023, 10, 4), 1),
    (2, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 4), "close", date(2023, 10, 4), 2),
    (3, date(2023, 10, 2), date(2023, 10, 4), "open", None, 1),
    (3, date(2023, 10, 3), date(2023, 10, 6), "open", None, 2),
]

# Create the DataFrame
B = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

# Apply the same filter as before
B_result = B.filter(f.col("rank") == 1).drop("rank")
display(B_result)

| id | date_start | date_end   | status | date_end_of_last_close |
|----|------------|------------|--------|------------------------|
| 1  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | open   | 2023-10-03             |
| 2  | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-02 | close  | 2023-10-04             |
| 3  | 2023-10-02 | 2023-10-04 | open   | NULL                   |
```

What is happening here? I don't trust pyspark right now, because I am applying a series of transformations by adding columns and using different window functions to later apply filters, and in view of these discrepancies I don't know what to do anymore.

## Update 2023-10-31

There seems to be some kind of problem in the latest version of pyspark (3.5.0). In the previous version (3.4.1) the script works as expected.

Comment: I ran your code. I got the expected result. Is your `display(A)` at fault here? `A_result.show(n=100, truncate=False)`  Here's my output of the first script you posted . 

https://pastebin.com/1W6rJ5pb

Comment: @user238607 It seems to be an issue with pyspark version. In pyspark 3.4.0 it runs as expected. In pyspark 3.5.0 I get into this error. Could you check it as well?

Comment: Yeah it seems there is issue with 3.5.0 version. If I materialize the dataframe using count, I get proper result. `print("count is:", A.cache().count())` `.count()` materializes the dataframe.  Here's my output with 3.5.0 which is correct one. https://pastebin.com/f9Tq3SkP

Comment: Yes it does! Do you know how can I open a issue to the pyspark team? It seems that they don't track their issues with GitHub but with Jira, only for members.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa  , Create an account. Provide a minimum reproducible example so that they can investigate on their end.